# My Bluetooth problem

Tags: bluetooth

I had a friend who Bluetooth me a website, but I can't seem to find it. I have checked my documents, videos, pictures and download section. Any suggestions where it might be?

Comment: Do you still remember any part of the name of the file that was sent? Then you could let your computer search for it. What desktop environment do you use? Would you also be able to run a command in a terminal?

Comment: Just as a guess, I'd check the /media directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found some of my Bluetooth files in the /Public folder in my Home directory. Don't know how or why, but they were there.